# Disable content of leftside column in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.8.1.  i want left side column on customer account page, but when i enable it, all the content of left column is shown here. i want only account related content on this page, but when i disable other content it is disable from other pages also.
[image]

so please tell me how to disable unnecessary content left side column for account page only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section is created from `yourtheme/layout` files..

So, go to xml files and comment or remove code..

That should help.

for shop by brand go to `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/manufacturer.xml`   file and comment below code bydefault this file in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/manufacturer.xml`
 so if you find this file in your base directory pls copy this into your theme so dont face any problem at the time of magento up-gradation

```
<block type="manufacturer/navigation" name="manufacturer.navigation.left" after="sidenav">
         <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="manufacturer/sidebar/enabledleft">
               <template>manufacturer/navigation/brands_nav.phtml</template>
          </action>
        </block>
```

for remove from account page go to customer.xml file and add this code

```
<reference name="left"> <remove name="manufacturer.navigation.left"/> </reference>
```

Comment: in which file i have chack and which code i have to remove?

Comment: For shop by brand go to app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/manufacturer.xml   file and comment this code